# Numpy create index/slicing programmatically from array

Tags: python, numpy

I can use `numpy.mgrid` as follows:

```
a = numpy.mgrid[x0:x1, y0:y1] # 2 dimensional
b = numpy.mgrid[x0:x1, y0:y1, z0:z1] # 3 dimensional
```

Now, I'd like to create the expression in brackets programmatically, because I do not know whether I have 1, 2, 3 or more dimensions. I'm looking for something like:

```
shape = np.array([[x0, x1], [y0, y1], ... maybe more dimensions ...])
idx = (s[0]:s[1] for s in shape)
a = numpy.mgrid[idx]
```

That gives at least a syntax error in the second line. **How can I properly generate those indices/slices programmatically?** (The mgrid here is rather an example/use case, the question is really about indexing in general.)

Comment: Generate the ranges with `idx = [range(s[0],s[1]) for s in shape]` and then use `meshgrid` : `np.meshgrid(*idx)`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the [`slice` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice).  For example:

```
shape = np.array([[0, 10], [0, 10]])
idx = tuple(slice(s[0],s[1], 1) for s in shape)
#yields the following
#(slice(0, 10, 1), slice(0, 10, 1))
np.mgrid[idx]
```

yields

```
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
        [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
        [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
        [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
        [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7],
        [8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8],
        [9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]],

       [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]])
```

Alternatively, you could use the Numpy shorthand [`np.s_`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.s_.html), e.g. `np.s_[0:10:1]`, instead of `slice(1, 10, 1)`, but they are equivalent objects.

Comment: `slice(s[0],s[1], None)` is a better translation of the intent

Comment: Or even better `slice(s[0], s[1])`.  I figured explicit is better than implicit for explanation.

Comment: Or with unpacking, `[slice(s,e) for s,e in shapes]`